# Double row with same height in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a table with the first column using two rows, so the following columns will have two rows, but with the same height. Some cells will have 2 or more lines and other none. So, I want them to have the same height, which would be half the height of the first row.

I've tried adding `min-width: 50%`, but it didn't work.

```css
.double-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.first-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.other-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.cell.upper {
  background: #00FF002F;
}

.cell.down {
  background: #FF00002F;
}
```

```html
<div class="double-row">
  <div class="col first-col">
    <h1>
      Double Row
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
      <p>
        Upper Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Agusbeche/pen/ZNvMPb

Comment: Maybe `height:50%` for cells?

Comment: you could use min-height and flex:1; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdrzNZ , but it obviously looks like a grid display, not flex. you have cols and a text spanning rows.

Answer (score 0):

you could just insert

`<p>&nbsp;</p>` in the other column for a quick fix. but thats not actually a nice solution, insted you should do this:

add `height: 50%;` to the children inside `col`

```css
.double-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.first-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.other-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cell {
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell.upper {
  background: #00FF002F;
}

.cell.down {
  background: #FF00002F;
}
```

```html
<div class="double-row">
  <div class="col first-col">
    <h1>
      Double Row
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
      <p>
        Upper Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text<br/>
        Bottom Text<br/>
        Bottom Text<br/>
        Bottom Text<br/>
        Bottom Text<br/>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
    <!-- OR DO THIS: <p>&nbsp;</p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it does work with only those lines, but I've just added some lines of text in the first column on the cell down to show that it isn't a final solution. Thanks. Could try with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: Well ofc my answer wasnt correct in that case, I have now updated my answer, you can now add as much Text as you like, and the cells will always be the same height. This is caused by your elements overflowing the actual size of 50%, you have to apply overflow: hidden, or give some more space. Would be nice if you accept my answer if it is sufficient for you

Comment: @G-Cyr I thought the question was about having the green and red parts at exactly 50%. If thats not the case, your comment is ofc right.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flex: 1` to the `cell` so that the rows share equal spaces. Also add `overflow: auto` so that any extra content will be scrolled if needed. If you want the three columns to share the horizontal space equally just add `flex: 1` to the `col` - see demo below:

```css
.double-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1; /* if columns must share equal space */
}

.first-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.other-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1; /* equal rows */
  overflow: auto; /* overflow if content is more */
}

.cell.upper {
  background: #00FF002F;
}

.cell.down {
  background: #FF00002F;
}

input {
  width: 100%; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="double-row">
  <div class="col first-col">
    <h1>
      Double Row
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
      <p>
        Upper Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without the overflow and equalling the height with the largest cell does not work properly with flexbox though - see the below demo with `min-height: 50%` to the `other-cell cell`. The container as a whole does not grow:

```css
.double-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1; /* if columns must share equal space */
}

.first-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.other-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.other-col .cell {
  min-height: 50%; /* added */
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1; /* equal rows */
}

.cell.upper {
  background: #00FF002F;
}

.cell.down {
  background: #FF00002F;
}

input {
  width: 100%; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="double-row">
  <div class="col first-col">
    <h1>
      Double Row
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
      <p>
        Upper Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

We can switch to CSS grids since the layout here has 2D behavior - to get the desired layout we can use a 3x2 grid with each cell occupying 1fr space (which means the rows will grow to be equal) - see demo below:

```css
.double-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 equal columns */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* 2 equal rows */
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.first-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2; /* occupy the first two rows */
}

.other-col {
  display: contents; /* promote the 'cell' to grid item */
}

.first-col + .other-col .cell {
  border-right: 1px solid grey; /* border fix */
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.cell.upper {
  background: #00FF002F;
  grid-row: 1; /* place in first row */
}

.cell.down {
  background: #FF00002F;
}

input {
  width: 100%; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="double-row">
  <div class="col first-col">
    <h1>
      Double Row
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
      <p>
        Upper Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col other-col">
    <div class="cell upper">
    </div>
    <div class="cell down">
      <input type="text">
      <p>
        Bottom Text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they dont have the same height, and also, i do not want to have an scroll. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Agusbeche I guess CSS grids will fare better here, take a look at the update answer, thanks!